# how to get minimum and maximum price from serializers?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

To get `minimum` and `maximum` price from serializers i used inbuilt types of function(min, max). but it's throwing me error: `'int' object is not iterable`.

views.py :

```
data = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
product_ser = FilterPriceSerializer(data,many=True)
filter_PriceData=[]
# print(product_ser.data)
for record in product_ser.data:
    value = json.dumps(record)
    temp = json.loads(value)

    price = temp['price']
    min_price = min(price)
    max_price = max(price)
    print(min_price)
    

    filter_PriceData.append({"price":price})
```

serializers.py :

```
class FilterPriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "price"
        ]
```

Comment: can you post serialized data?

Comment: @VishalSingh  yes, i have edited my question.

Comment: I was asking for the value `product_ser.data` but I've answered the question based on the info available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't need a for loop, you can directly use min, max on `product_ser.data` to calculate the maximum and minimum price.

```
data = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
product_ser = FilterPriceSerializer(data, many=True)

min_price = min(product_ser.data, key=lambda x: x["price"])
max_price = max(product_ser.data, key=lambda x: x["price"])
```

Comment: Also how to iter only `price` data using above list comprehension method?